# Print all leaf nodes of a Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to print all the leaf nodes in ascending order, but the output is not as I expect.
Insert function:

```
Node *insert(Node **root, int k)
{
    if(*root == NULL)
    {
        Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node ));
        if(newNode == NULL)
            return NULL;
        newNode->key = k;
        newNode->left = NULL;
        newNode->right = NULL;
        (*root) = newNode; 
        return newNode; 
    }
    if(k < (*root)->key)
        return insert(&((*root)->left),k);
    else
        return insert((&(*root)->right),k);
}
```

Ascending order print function:

```
void printLeafs(Node *r)
{
    if (r != NULL)
    {
        if(r->right == NULL && r->left == NULL)
           printf("%d ", r->key);
        printLeafs(r->right);       
        printLeafs(r->left);
        
    }
}
```

Example:
Input: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Correct Output: 4 7 8 9
**My output**: 9

Other example:
[image: bst]

In this tree my code **should** print:
4 6 7 9 10
Any thoughts?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Also please tell us what attempts of debugging you have made, and what information you have gotten from it.

Comment: This looks like homework or learning so I'm not going to solve it outright but I do have a question/hint. When you "insert" a node... where are  you actually tying it to the rest of the tree above it?

Comment: For anything related to trees or lists or similar, I also recommend you spend some time with pen and paper before writing code. Try to draw the tree you're supposed to get using the supplied input. Is the tree looking like you expect? It's also good to use pen and paper when debugging, to draw out the tree as it grows while you're stepping through the code.

Comment: Maybe the goal is to keep the code as is and find an **input** which results in the stated desired output? I would love that to be the teachers idea. Let me know if that is the case. However, I think it is impossible to have 7,8,9 in leafs.

Comment: What is it about the output "4 7 8 9" that makes it correct? This highly depends on the algorithm used to insert elements into the tree. It looks like the "correct output" results from some "balancing" algorithm such as red-black tree insertion.

Comment: @IanAbbott Interesting. But that would mean that "Binary search tree" is imprecise, not to say wrong. Wouldn't it? Also, any tree would either have all retrievable keys inside leafs, or be unable to have all of 7,8,9 in leafs.

Comment: James, would you accept an answer which proves that no binary search tree can have the desired output as all-and-only-leafs for the shown input? (first example) You would probably impress your teacher.

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes, I ended up realizing that the desired output to a binary search tree is impossible.

Comment: The diagram shown looks like a binary min-heap tree rather than a binary search tree.

Comment: @Yunnosch I was just guessing about the balancing algorithm, but it's a moot point since the example diagram added to the question is not a binary search tree. (Also, the r-b algorithm I ran on the input 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ended up putting 4 at the top of the tree.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only pribnt leafs, because of

```
if(r->right == NULL && r->left == NULL)
```

And for the very special input `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` you only have a single leaf, the 9.

So your code is doing the "Print all leaf nodes of a Binary Tree" with stress on the **leaf** nodes.

But if you want instead **all** nodes:

To fix you should not skip the value in the non-leaf nodes and instead print it in the right place:

```c
printLeafs(r->right);       
printf("%d ", r->key);
printLeafs(r->left);
```

For fun and insight, try a different input on your unchanged code:
`5 4 6 2 1 3 8 7 9`

Note: I admittedly ignored the desired output, since it neither matches "all leafs" nor "all". My answer matches the (retrospect) assumption that you have a copy-paste error and the desired output is `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`.

Comment: So one could actually say that the code the OP shows really does what the OP is asking about: Display only the *leaf* nodes. :) In other words, the problem the OP have is not what the OP thinks.

Comment: I just noticed and edited. Which of course means I agree fully. Thanks for mentioning anyway. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Also, from the OP's expected output, it seems that what's wanted is not only leaf nodes, but perhaps also nodes with only one child?

Comment: The desired output is strange. Admittedly so strange that I ignored it. Will ponder. If you have an insight let know. It seems however not to match "nodes with only one child" either. This is assuming that the input results in this degenerate tree: `1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8->9` @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: I forgot to say that it is a Binary Research Tree.

Comment: I still doubt that any binary search tree (I doubt the "research") can have 7,8 AND 9 in leafs. Assuming the keys to be integer.

Comment: Yes it was my mistake, I ended up confusing the types of trees, thanks for the warning @Yunnosch

Comment: There still is a conflict between my answer and the desired output. Can we resolve it? Please either tell me what I should change or change the desired output in the question.